# Иерархическая кластеризация на Питоне

Tags: python

У меня есть некоторый df https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zBxmFHAyIN5D9gbKatld0064ZBOsZueX3K8LB9UFZ_c/edit?usp=sharing, в котором в строках находятся люди, а в столбцах их ответы на вопросы опросника.
Кластеризовать я хочу не людей, а их ответы, чтобы знать, склеиваются ли каким-либо образом опросниковые вопросы в смысловые кластеры, поэтому перед процедурой я транспонирую свой датафрейм: `df1 = df.transpose()` .

Затем начинаю сам анализ, в котором строю дендрограмму и делаю саму кластеризацию:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 4))
dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(df1, method='ward'))# create clusters
hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=9, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'ward')# save clusters for chart
y_hc = hc.fit_predict(df1)
```

Но при этом мои метки вопросов (их название и номер) теряются. Можно ли их как-то сохранить, чтобы они отображались и на дендрограмме, и в самом результате кластеризации?